Do I have a moisture problem in my ceiling?
We recently finished renovating an upstairs bathroom, which included relocating a shower. As part of that, minor water damage occurred to the ceiling in the room below the bath. I have a moisture meter and confirmed the ceiling had dried out before it was closed up.
Now the mystery- A few days after the ceiling was repainted, we notice ceiling stain (it could be an old stain poking through the paint job or a new stain). I tested the area around the stain and the moisture meter was reading around 50% in one small spot. The area is not immediately beneath any fixture nor was there any obvious source for moisture, but the area could be below the shower supply / drain lines and below an adjacent to a forced hot water radiator. My hypothesis was maybe a pinhole leak in the shower drain line, which might explain the relatively minor moisture in the ceiling.
We ran the shower for severe hours to test this over the course of several days and the moisture readings gradually climbed up to 75% then 100% in spots (seemingly increasing only when the shower was run), with an overall 'potentially wet' area of about 18in x 6in in a crescent shape. In an attempt to confirm - we poked a few tiny holes in the ceiling, but there was no water coming through even with the shower running. I even put a few pool test strips up through the holes at an angle, and again no sign of moisture on the strips. The readings have remained in the 90-100% range over several days since.
My contractor says ‘don’t trust the moisture meter’ and 'if there were a leak, you'd have water dripping out of the holes'. I know moisture meters aren't perfect and fluctuate with things like temperature, but I can’t come up with an explanation for the readings growing from 50% to 100%, and I am nervous letting him 'off the hook' for potentially soggy drywall from his work.
My moisture meter is a General Tools Digital Moisture Meter MMD7NP, which has served me faithfully over the years and never given me any reason to question its accuracy until now.
So I'm left uncertain if this drywall is actually wet, and if so, what from. Do we paint over the stain and stop worrying? Cut open the ceiling? Or Something else?

The only way to know for sure if you have an active leak is to cut open the ceiling and take a look at the pipes and drain. This is not a difficult task, and then you'll know for sure.
If there's high humidity in your area, on warm days the cold water running through the pipes will make the air around the pipes condensate, creating water droplets around the pipes, some of which might be dropping on the ceiling below. There's nothing a plumber can do about that.
On the other hand, it's still possible that you are just seeing the previous stain bleeding through. Use an oil-based stain-blocker paint primer and that should take care of that.
